# What is graph of graph of $y = (x-1)\sqrt{x}$

Tags: graphing-functions

The book "A student's Guide to Fourier Transforms" 3rd edition, by J.F.James, published by C.U.P., on pages 20 and 21 quotes the equation $y = (x-1)\sqrt{x}$ as an example of one that does not meet the criteria for a Fourier transform because it is a two valued function. However the graph given is triple valued in places, with a continuous loop like that traced by an aeroplane looping the loop.

I cannot reconcile these, so please can anybody help with making sense of it, perhaps by showing what the plot of this equation really does look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [footnote](http://books.google.com/books?id=_T99VW0ARfkC&lpg=PP1&dq=%22A%20student%27s%20Guide%20to%20Fourier%20Transforms%22%203rd%20edition&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q&f=false) or [figure](http://books.google.com/books?id=_T99VW0ARfkC&lpg=PP1&dq=%22A%20student%27s%20Guide%20to%20Fourier%20Transforms%22%203rd%20edition&pg=PA21#v=onepage&q&f=false) in the book is incorrect. The equation $(1 - y) (x^2 + y^2) = 2 x^2$ describes a graph similar to the figure in the book.

Answer (score 1):

$y=(x-1)\sqrt x$ is nicely single valued if you view $y$ as a function of $x$.  It is only defined for $x \ge 0$.  It does have a vertical tangent at $x=0$.  If you view $x$ as a function of $y$, it is double valued on $y \le 0, x \le 1$  A plot is below

[image]